Appkit & Cocoa - How to support editing for a view-based NSTableView?
So I have a view-based NSTableView whose contents are stored in an NSMutableArray. Basically I created a table view in the storyboard and inserted a control of type "Image and Text Table CellView", this table just holds a string and an image, for this example it's just a quiz and a grade:

Now I would like to somehow implement a function to allow me  to edit these two strings, the NSTableViewDataSource has this method called tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row: but it states that it should not be used for view-based tables and that I should instead use:

target/action to set each item in the view cell.

But what does that mean exactly? Am I supposed to subclass NSTableView?
